# HDFS file upload failed in the middle

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, talend

I am building a prototype using CDH 5.1. I am using a 3 node cluster. 
While uploading the data from the database to the HDFS the resource manager server aborted unexpectedly.
Now I see a file of size 3 GB in the HDFS.

Issue :

Total rows in the DB for the query is 42600000. The Server stopped after 7641242 rows transferred. I am using Talend to do the ETL. I know this time I will not be able to do much other than start the process all over again.

Is there a way we can mitigate this issue in future?

Update after running the dfsadmin command :

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -report
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

Configured Capacity: 338351861760 (315.11 GB)
Present Capacity: 314764926976 (293.15 GB)
DFS Remaining: 303901577216 (283.03 GB)
DFS Used: 10863349760 (10.12 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.45%
Under replicated blocks: 1
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 1
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 10.215.204.196:50010 (txwlcloud3)
Hostname: txwlcloud3
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 112783953920 (105.04 GB)
DFS Used: 3623538688 (3.37 GB)
Non DFS Used: 2971234304 (2.77 GB)
DFS Remaining: 106189180928 (98.90 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.21%
DFS Remaining%: 94.15%
Configured Cache Capacity: 522190848 (498 MB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 522190848 (498 MB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Last contact: Tue Sep 30 10:55:11 CDT 2014


Name: 10.215.204.203:50010 (txwlcloud2)
Hostname: txwlcloud2
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 112783953920 (105.04 GB)
DFS Used: 3645382656 (3.40 GB)
Non DFS Used: 2970497024 (2.77 GB)
DFS Remaining: 106168074240 (98.88 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.23%
DFS Remaining%: 94.13%
Configured Cache Capacity: 815792128 (778 MB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 815792128 (778 MB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Last contact: Tue Sep 30 10:55:10 CDT 2014


Name: 10.215.204.213:50010 (txwlcloud1)
Hostname: txwlcloud1
Rack: /default
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 112783953920 (105.04 GB)
DFS Used: 3594428416 (3.35 GB)
Non DFS Used: 17645203456 (16.43 GB)
DFS Remaining: 91544322048 (85.26 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.19%
DFS Remaining%: 81.17%
Configured Cache Capacity: 3145728 (3 MB)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 3145728 (3 MB)
Cache Used%: 0.00%
Cache Remaining%: 100.00%
Last contact: Tue Sep 30 10:55:10 CDT 2014
```

Comment: try `hadoop dfsadmin -report` on ur console and check how much space is available in the cluster. That might be the issue.

Comment: You need to try and find the root cause really. If it's a lack of available space then there's no component that will directly allow you to check if there's room on the cluster although you could maybe do it yourself in a tJava component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it is the issue with space. I ran the dfs admin command and updated my original request with the information. I am trying to 1) is there a way so that if such crashes happen in the future we can resume the data load process instead of start all over again?